# Separate my checkbox Widget to a function not work

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to move the code for my checkbox to its own Widget function, so I don't have to repeat the code for it.  However, it doesn't seem to work for some reasons.
Here's my code for the checkbox function:

```
 Widget getCheckbox(bool? value, String label) {

    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: 170,
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        value: value,
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        onChanged: (newBool) {
          value = newBool!;
          setState(() {});
        },
        title: Text(label),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm calling this function as the code below:

```
getCheckbox(plane, 'Plane')
```

It doesn't work for some reasons, If I just move the checkbox code and replace the calling line code `getCheckbox(plane, 'Plane')` then it works.

My question, why is not working when I separate out the code to its own function?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way in flutter to pass in the name of the variable as a String then I can refer to it inside the function.  Example:  If I have a variable `bool _plane = false` then I can pass the variable name as String `_plane` to the function .  Inside the function, I can refer to it (example:` ${_plane}`)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"? What are the differences in the behavior between using the function vs using `SizedBox` directly?

Comment: When moving the code to a function,  the checkbox is not change to checked when I click on it.  It just show the checkbox but it doesn't change.

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing in your `build()` function, when you are calling the function, you are always passing it the same value, which is never changing. If you do want to use the function, you may need to pass a callback to it as well that actually changes the value you are trying to toggle in the `setState()` call, or some other way to ensure the value being passed to the function is actually getting updated, otherwise you will keep rebuilding with the same values

Comment: nice idea, how would you implement that callback function for this one.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code first, and then to go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use classes instead of functions to create a widget and let the `onChanged` callback to handle what happen when the checkbox's value changes.

```dart
class CustomCheckBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomCheckBox({
    super.key,
    this.value,
    required this.label,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  final bool? value;
  final String label;
  final ValueChanged<bool?>? onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: 170,
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        value: value,
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        title: Text(label),
        onChanged: onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// usage
CustomCheckBox(
  label: 'label',
  value: true,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() => myBool = value!);
  },
);
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm learning new things today.  Thanks @Charles!